# How to sum the total of each row?

Tags: postgresql

Data is

```html
    cases            e_id
    NULL             2820   
    3                3107   
    5                2987   
    66               2987   
    18               503
    26               503    
    1                503    
    108              503
    32               503
    4                503
```

Expectation

On the basis of unique `e_id` , sum the `cases` in extreme `count` column.

```html
        cases            e_id         count
        NULL             2820          0
        3                3107          3
        5                2987          71
        66               2987          71
        18               503           189
        26               503           189
        1                503           189
        108              503           189
        32               503           189
        4                503           189
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done using a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html):

```
select cases, e_id, sum(cases) over (partition by e_id) as count
from the_table;
```